# GitHub self-hosted runner creates Repo folder twice

Tags: git, github, github-actions, windows-server

I have set up a self-hosted runner on my Windows server and I have set up the necessary workflows needed to auto deploy/build my repo on the server. While setting up the runner, I configured the work folder to be a folder called `repos` in the same directory.

What I want is for the folder structure of my runner to be:

```
C:\deploy
    - ...other runner files & folders
    - config.cmd
    - run.cmd
    - repos/
        - ..."_actions/", "_temp/" etc.
        - <my repo name>/
            - ...the content of my repo...
```

But I see that the runner creates 2 folders inside each other with the name of my repo. So in my case the path to my build files are `C:\deploy\repos\<repo name>\<repo name>\build`. Is there a way to prevent this double folder structure?

Comment: I think the first folder is the repo that owns the workflow and the second is a list of workflows it checks out. You can explicitly set the path where it should check out to: `with:  path: "./"`

Comment: @jessehouwing, setting the path to "./" made no difference. So I tried "./test/" and it made a new folder at the path `C:\deploy\repos\<repo name>\<repo name>\test\ `. So then I tried setting the path to "../", but then github says `Error: Repository path 'C:\deploy\repos\<repo name>' is not under 'C:\deploy\repos\<repo name>\<repo name>`

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: @BillDagg, unfortunately not. I have just kept this as is. I can't seem to find anything about this matter anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a fix for this. I've used the default names of the parent directories here.

I went into `actions-runner/_work/_PipelineMapping/[user]/[repo]/PipelineFolder.json`

I changed the value for `workspaceDirectory` from `[repo]/[repo]` to just `[repo]`.